# How to get the button to align together in different div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the button at the bottom of each div to align together to the other div.

I have tried using but it still can't work.

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

This is my current work : https://www.bootply.com/NrkiUsvKa5

I'm trying to get to this result without calling break : https://www.bootply.com/gdP1LUvflA

Comment: set a fixed height and then set it to the bottom, it will work.

Comment: You could work with a flexbox set up and let that help you lining it out. This way it will always be on the bottom, no matter how long your longest column is. read more about it here https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i noted in the comments, you can add a flexbox propperty to your row (i added it as a class in my example, see bootply link), and it will line out perfectly.

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Check for the outcome here: https://www.bootply.com/iTaThCIrjb

For more documentation, read this article: https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column

Apply the flexbox and it wouldn't matter how long you would make your lines. This would render the awnser with a fixed height obsolete

Comment: thank you! I still need add height:450px to the .flexbox-container for it to work. Somehow the flexbox will still cover some of my wordings

Comment: Yes because your button is on the bottom of this. You could fix it with a margin bottom.l on your <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to a fixed height and use:

```
#btn{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make relative the container div of the button and then give absolute position like below example.

```
<style>
.btnwrap { position:relative}
.btn { position:absolute; bottom:0}
</style>

<div class="btnwrap">
<a class="btn">Button</div>
</div>
```